# Dictionary to pretty table format

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting, prettytable

anyone can tell me how can I solve this please;
I have this:

```
dct = {
"A": ['None', 'None', 'None'],
"B" : ['None', 'None', 'None'] ,
"C": ['None', 'None', 'None'] ,
"D": ['None', 'None', 'None']
```

}

and I am getting this:
[image]

but, i want get this format:
[image]

any ideas please ?

this is my code:

```
def pretty_table(dct):
  table = PrettyTable()
  for c in dct.keys():
     table.add_column(c, [])
  table.add_row([dct.get(c, "") for c in dct.keys()])
  print(table)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert each list in the cell as a string composed by the elements joined through a newline:

```
def pretty_table(dct):
  table = PrettyTable()
  for c in dct.keys():
     table.add_column(c, [])
  table.add_row(['\n'.join(dct[c]) for c in dct.keys()])
  print(table)
```

This will be the output:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |
+------+------+------+------+
| None | None | None | None |
| None | None | None | None |
| None | None | None | None |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Good catch @Flavio

Comment: Sure,  it does :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use `zip()`:

```py
def pretty_table(dct):
    table = PrettyTable(dct.keys())
    table.add_rows(zip(*dct.values()))
    print(table)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code?

Comment: Hey, yes of course:
`table = PrettyTable(dct.keys())` takes the keys of the dictonary: A,B,C and D and initializes a PrettyTable with them as column names.
`table.add_rows(zip(*dct.values()))` : `dct.values() ` returns all dictonary values in a list, so we got a list of lists: `[ [None, None, None], [None, None, None],...]`. The `*` takes each element of that list an uses it as a argument for the zip function. In this case the zip function gets four times the list `[None, None, None]` and combines the first element of each list into a tuple, then the second and so on. This are the rows then.